# unable install pear dependencies

Tags: php, drupal, pear

I am  new to php and drupal i want install below commands

**sudo pear install mail
sudo pear install Net_SMTP
sudo pear Auth_SASL
sudo pear install mail_mime**

I tried many ways to install but i saw result  below like this 
sudo pear install mail_mime
[sudo] password for ******: 
downloading Mail_Mime-1.10.0.tgz ...
Starting to download Mail_Mime-1.10.0.tgz (35,375 bytes)
.........done: 35,375 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "/build/php5-0LI9sl/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download/Mail_Mime-1.10.0.tgz"
Download of "pear/mail_mime" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pear/Mail_Mime"
Download failed
install failed.

can any one help me from this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the Archive_Tar PEAR component needs to be replaced/upgraded.

Do this first:

```
$ sudo pear upgrade -Z pear/Archive_Tar
```

It would also be a good time to update your pear installation:

```
$ sudo pear upgrade pear
```

And then try the other steps again:

```
$ sudo pear install mail Net_SMTP Auth_SASL mail_mime
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer suggest to first run

```
 $ pear upgrade -Z pear/Archive_Tar
```

This however also gave me the error: *Download of "pear/Archive_Tar" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive*.
This did however download the **Archive_Tar-1.4.2.tar** file into my **php\PEAR\download** directory.

Next, I replaced the **php\PEAR\Archive\Tar.php** file with the one in **php\PEAR\download\Archive_Tar-1.4.2.tar\Archive_Tar-1.4.2\Archive\Tar.php** (You can rename the one in php\PEAR\Archive\ first, just to be safe).

This fixed the "*not a valid package archive*"-errors for me.

As suggested in the accepted answer, it would now be a good time to update your pear installation.

Comment: Thanks, I also needed the additional trick of manually replacing the Archive\Tar.php file when the pear upgrade -Z pear/Archive_Tar and pear upgrade pear failed

Everything works now that the Tar file has been fixed.